# jQuery Fancybox changing transition settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, gallery, image-gallery

I have a fancybox gallery on this [Site](http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/showroom.html)

this is my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{$("a[rel=gal]").fancybox({
            'transitionIn' : 'fade',
            'transitionOut' : 'fade'    
        });});
```

What needs to be done to create a transition (fade in & out) like on this site [Site](http://www.bruk-metr.pl/galeria.php?id=13) instead of sliding?
And how can we delete the next title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with fancybox but here is the code they are using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a[rel=gal]").fancybox();

});
```

So just go with the default options like they did.

**Update**

I just checked fancybox and it seems like fade is the transition you are looking for. However, on your website the active transition is "elastic". Perhaps you didn't commit the changes?

**Update 2**

I'm sorry, but your question is misleading. I had to dig into your code to realize that you were using the second version of this plugin, which uses different options. You can find the documentation here : http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ .
Try setting these options

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    'nextEffect': 'fade',
    'prevEffect': 'fade'
    });

});
```

P.S Give your gallery a class "fancybox". 
Here is today's lesson: it is always better to select elements by their native attributes(like the class) instead of making new ones up.

Comment: I tried elastic and fade but the default transition does not change

Comment: Ok perfect. If you can tell me how I delete the next/preview title that appears on hovering the next arrow then I will accept your answer.

Comment: In your fancybox.js file search for title="Next" and title="Previous" .Then remove them both. The idea of stack overflow is to help others. Please keep that in mind. I don't do it for points, nor I encourage you to do so. Return the favor by participating.

Comment: Btw, I just noticed that you've included the plugin 2 times. Your first one is the fancybox.js file and the second minified version is fancybox.pack.js. Follow my instructions for one of them and delete the other.

Comment: Ok I deleted the other one. At the moment I am looking for the title="Next" and title="Previous" line, if you know the exact number of that line please let me know.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29563/discussion-between-slytael-and-daniel-hernandez)